# Scrollable CStatic on CDialog

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a CStatic picture control on a CDialog that I use to draw content:

CMyDrawingControl.h

```
CMyDrawingControl : CStatic
{
   //Constructor, Destructor, other items

   //End Constructor, Destructor, other items
public:
   void DrawStuff(CDC *dc);

protected:
   afx_msg void OnPaint();
   afx_msg void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
}
```

CMyDrawingControl.cpp

```
CMyDrawingControl::CMyDrawingControl
{

}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDrawingControl, CStatic)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyDrawingControl)
ON_WM_VSCROLL()
ON_WM_PAINT()
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyDrawingControl::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    //determine delta
    ScrollWindow(0, -delta);
    Invalidate();
    UpdateWindow();
}

void CMyDrawingControl::OnPaint()
{
    CPaint dc(this);

    DrawStuff(&dc);
}

void CMyDrawingControl::DrawStuff(CDC *dc)
{
    dc->SetMapMode(MM_LOMETRIC);

    //draw on dc
    //text, lines, shapes, etc
}
```

However the content is usually bigger than the control so I need to be able to scroll the content. CScrollView automatically handles by drawing to the view in OnDraw, but I can't seem to get it to work in OnPaint(). The control either will draw blank or has a lot of repeated content when scrolling.

I'm basically trying to duplicate the exact behavior of CScrollView on a CDialog; I've seen some posts that come close to this, but I don't want to implement a CDocument and a CView.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much simpler to use a read only edit control.

Beside scrolling this also makes it possible that the user can select and copy parts of the text.